# Returning matched lookahead groups

Tags: javascript, regex

Good day,

I am trying to return groups of 3 digits of a given string where digits are "consumed" twice in JavaScript:

From a string `"123 456"` I would like `exec` to return `["1", "12"]` for the first match, `["2", "23"]` and so on.

I tried using a lookahead like this:

```
let exp = /(\d(?=\d\d))/g;    
let match;

while(match = exp.exec("1234 454")) {
    console.log(match);
}
```

This, will however still only each digit which precedes two digits.

Does someone have a solution? I have searched but am not exactly sure what to search for so I might have missed something.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture inside a positive lookahead here:

```js
let exp = /(?=((\d)\d))/g;    
let match;
while(match = exp.exec("1234 454")) {
     if (match.index === exp.lastIndex) { // \ 
        exp.lastIndex++;                  // - Prevent infinite loop
    }                                     // /
    console.log([match[1], match[2]]);    // Print the output
}
```

The `(?=((\d)\d))` pattern matches a location followed with 2 digits (captured into Group 1) the first being captured into Group 2.

Comment: I see, thanks! I have one question, though: I don't see why you need to prevent infinite loops from happening? I don't see how they should happen, normally match.index is updated automatically after each call, isn't it?

Comment: @Sebastian No, since each match is of zero length. Regex index must be advanced "manually".

Comment: That's because (?=) doesn't "consume" any matches anymore, isn't it (compared to my previous attempt)?

Comment: JS RegExp lastIndex property is only advanced upon a non-empty match. Non-consuming patterns do not hold any value, they are empty, thus, you must advance it manually.